# TweenMax not working

Tags: coffeescript, gsap

Whenever I try to use TweenMax, the animation works, but the duration of the animation is 0, even when I specify the duration!
This is my CoffeeScript code:

```
    $ ->
      $("header").click ->
        TweenLite.to("header", 0.5, {"background-color": "coral"})
```

Answer (score 1):

In GSAP the `target` accepts a `string`, `array`, or `jQuery collection wrapper`.

http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/to/

If your using your site with a CMS that uses jQuery you could define your selector engine:

```
// place above all your TweenLite code
TweenLite.selector = jQuery;
```

Sometimes a CMS system might take ownership of the factory symbol `$`

```
// define selector for simple selectors to work with GSAP and a CMS
TweenLite.selector = jQuery;

// then add your code like you have above
$ ->
  $("header").click ->
    TweenLite.to("header", 0.5, {"background-color": "coral"})
```

Once you define your selector than you can use it like you were doing, as a string, without a jQuery collection wrapper. GSAP accepts

> **target : Object**
>
> Target object (or array of objects) whose properties should be
>   affected. When animating DOM elements, the target can be: a single
>   element, an array of elements, a jQuery object (or similar), or a CSS
>   selector string like “#feature” or “h2.author”. GSAP will pass
>   selector strings to a selector engine like jQuery or Sizzle (if one is
>   detected or defined through TweenLite.selector), falling back to
>   document.querySelectorAll().

But keep in mind you only need to define `TweenLite.selector` if your using GSAP in a website that has taken ownership of the factory symbol `$`

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, it looks as though the first argument for the `.to()` method expects a jQuery object, not a string.

Maybe try this:

```
$ ->
  $("header").click ->
    TweenLite.to($(this), 0.5, { "background-color": "coral" })
```

Or this:

```
$ ->
  $header = $("header")

  $header.click ->
    TweenLite.to($header, 0.5, { "background-color": "coral" })
```

Here is a link to the cheatsheet I referenced:

https://ihatetomatoes.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/GreenSock-Cheatsheet2.png

Comment: The first parameter for the `to()` method can be an array, an object, a jQuery selector, or a string selector http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineLite/to/ :)